# Displaying the foreign key children and descendants relationship for all tables

Tags: sql, database, db2, syntax-error

I am trying to display all the foreign key children and relationships in the database which I am working on (>300 databases) and have stumbled upon this sql query which could help me.

> https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1301foreignkey/index.html

I have copied it directly from the website above but it has failed to compile and gave me errors:

> Error Code 104, 727

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=prior;_parents)
connect by;PRIOR, DRIVER=4.15.113
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098,     SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;prior|_parents)
connect by|PRIOR, DRIVER=4.15.113
SQLState:  56098
ErrorCode: -727
```

Can I have some help? Thank you.

```
with root_parents (root_parent_schema, root_parent_name) AS
 (select tabschema, tabname
    from syscat.tables
    where parents = 0 and children > 0)
select 
  substr(connect_by_root reftabname,1,11) as root,
  substr(level, 1,5) as lvl,
  substr(reftabname) as parent, 
  substr(tabname,1,10) as child, 
  substr(constname,1,5) as cnst, 
  substr(sys_connect_by_path(reftabname, '->') || '->' || 
  substr(tabname,1,20),1,42) as chain
from syscat.references
start with (reftabschema,reftabname) in (select root_parent_schema, 
                                    root_parent_name from root_parents)
connect by prior  tabname = reftabname and tabschema = reftabschema;
```

Comment: What DBMS are you actually using? The tag says MySQL the error message points to DB2.

Comment: Apologise for the mistake. Wrong tag. :)

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: `CONNECT BY` is Oracle proprietary syntax for recursive queries, which requires enabling Oracle compatibility features in Db2 (which the article author notes, by the way).

Comment: @mustaccio Db2 for i also supports `CONNECT BY`